# Cardinality of reduced products

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, model-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A}_i (i \in I)$ is a family of $L$-structures and consider the reduced product $\mathcal{A}$ of this family by a filter $F \subseteq \mathcal{P}(I)$. Is there a way to determine the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}$ in terms of the cardinality of each of its factors? For example, suppose each $\mathcal{A}_i$ is finite, but there is no bound on their cardinalities. Does it follow that $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, suppose each $\mathcal{A}_i$ is finite, but there is no bound on their cardinalities. Does it follow that $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite?

No, not necessarily. For example, consider $\mathcal A_i = \{0, 1, \ldots, i \}$ and let $F \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ be the principal ultrafilter given by
$$
x \in F \iff 0 \in x.
$$
Then, for any $[f]$ in the reduced ultrapower, we have
$$
\{ n \in \mathbb N \mid f(n) = 0 \} \ni 0
$$
and hence $[f] = [\{(0,0)\}]$, i.e. $\prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathcal{A}_i / F = \{[(0,0)] \}$ has cardinality $1$.

On the other hand, clearly $\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{A}_i / F$ has cardinality $\le \mathrm{card}(\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{A}_i)$ and equality is possible.

Comment: In fact, if the left-hand side is infinite, you get equality.

Comment: Hmm, I think this example is an instance of the fact that, if $U$ is principal, then $\mathcal{A} \simeq \mathcal{A}_k$ for some $k \in I$. What if I require the filter to be non-principal, e.g. the Fréchet filter?

Comment: In my example, if $F$ is not principal, then the reduced ultrapower would be infinite. However, it's still possible for a non-principal filter of finite but unbounded components to generate a finite reduced product. For example: Let $X \in F$ and let $\mathcal A_i = \{0\}$ for all $i \in X$. Then the reduced product still has cardinality $0$, independent of what the $\mathcal A_i$ are outside of indices in $X$.

Comment: The cardinality in the comment above is, of course, supposed to be $1$, not $0$.